# Adding a Google Hangout button to my site. When visitors click it, is there anyway for it to initiate a hangout with me?

Tags: google, google-hangouts

Basically, I am adding a Google Hangout button to my Contact page. The idea is for my visitors to be able to press the button and for it to initiate a Google Hangout with me.

Is this possible?
Is there anything that makes this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research, doesn't look like this feature is available yet.
http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-plus-discuss/-cJeQltplhE

Answer (score 3):

I found this on [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button):

1. Get a Developer APP ID

   The button must contain the app ID of your Hangout app or extension. Go to the [APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/), select the Hangouts project you want the button to start, then copy the app ID from the current URL at the top of the browser, like this — it's the number that follows "project:", and will be at least 12 digits long.

   `//code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/#project:123456789012`
2. Test your app

   To test starting a hangout with your app or extension running in it, go to:

   `https://hangoutsapi.talkgadget.google.com/hangouts/_?gid=APP_ID`

   where you replace APP_ID with the value from the previous step. This URL is used in the next step.
3. Adding a button to your page

   The Hangout button comes in the following four sizes: 79×15, 86×20, 24×100, 60×230. Each button is followed by the HTML code you should embed in your page. Replace APP_ID with your application's app ID (from above).

   This is the code for the 79×15 button:

   `<a href="https://plus.google.com/hangouts/_?gid=APP_ID" style="text-decoration:none;">
   <img src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/stars/hangout/1/gplus-hangout-15x79-normal.png"
   alt="Start a Hangout"
   style="border:0;width:79px;height:15px;"/>
   </a>`

   Click on the button to start a hangout with your public application or extension running inside it.

Comment: I followed those steps, and had no luck. When I set the proper code project up, it would open up an empty Google Hangout. I tested this from another computer.